# Data-driven, high-dimensional feature selection strategies

Tags: feature-selection

I am working on a biomedical/healthcare data science problem.

I have a dataset of 600 samples, ~6000 variables and class label as "positive" or "negative". I want to perform feature selection on this high-dimensional data. I want to know what are the best strategies to find which feature is most contributing here. Typically, I design a binary classifier (SVM, NB, RF or ANN) and then use information gain or RandomForest to assess the feature importance. Here, my variable space is ten-times more than my instances - hence am not comfortable with this approach.

Is there any better strategy to reduce the feature space in a data-driven way?

Comment: What about trying dimensionality reduction?

Comment: Not data-driven? So, on theoretical basis maybe? Don't think that is a good idea. I would try something like Supervised Principal Components.

Comment: Why not try lasso regression.  It has been developed specifically for those kind of problems, fewer data than dimensions)   (eg using glmnet package in R)..

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrBlekh for suggestion on dimensionality reduction. I was using one of such approach, but wanted to see what are best way test all features without overfitting the model.

Comment: @D.Stroet: Thanks for the point to supervised PCA. My iddea is to pick top features without any sort of weighting.

Comment: Thanks Sean - We are using LASSO for several projects, but I was interested to see if there is any other approaches out there.

Comment: I see. However, unless it is customary in your subject domain, I'm not sure that it is feasible to have and analyze so high-dimensional models.